# How to create new folders on desktop with a batch script

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Can someone please tell me how to create new folders on desktop with a batch script?

I can't find any simple tutorials on the internet. I just want a straightforward script that creates folders on my desktop.

Comment: create folder with what name?

Answer (score 3):

There is an environment variable named: **`"USERPROFILE"`**

This variable holds the path of your "home" directory under the **`"Users"`** folder on the drive where Windows is installed.

If you open a command prompt window, and type: **`echo "%USERPROFILE%"`**, you will see something like:

```
C:\>echo "%USERPROFILE%"
"C:\Users\your-user-name"
```

This will also be available as: **`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`** where:

```
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\your-user-name
```

This folder is the ***Parent*** folder for your **`"Desktop"`** folder. So, if you wanted to create a folder named **`"MyNewFolder"`**, on your ***Desktop*** from a command window or a batch script, the command would look like this:

```
C:\>md "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MyNewFolder"
```

These variables (**`USERPROFILE`**,  **`HOMEDRIVE`**, **`HOMEPATH`**) are available on **Windows 7** (and probably also **Windows Vista** and **Windows 8**). For **Windows XP** and **Windows 98**, this would have been found under the **`C:\Documents and Settings`** folder.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in a text file, rename it to `[someFilename].bat`, and save the file on the desktop:

```
@echo off
set /p x= 
mkdir %x%
```

Double-click it, and you will be prompted for input. Enter the desired folder name, and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)
2. Open up **Notepad**
3. In the blank document, type:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   mkdir C:\path\to\dersired\directory
   ```
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
5. For filetype, choose `All files`
6. Save it
7. Open a command prompt
8. Type in: `C:\cygwin\bin\bash C:\path\to\script\script.sh`

You can put other stuff in the bash script too.

Comment: maybe installing Cygwin isn't the simplest solution to this question.

Comment: @stib That's probably true, but I feel like having Cygwin installed would have tremendous value in the future as well.

Comment: So would wiping the Windows partition and installing Linux, or learning Lisp so you could write a program to do it. But not a simple solution to the problem.

Comment: True! I totally agree =)

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems can't find the path when using `%userprofile%` with `cd`, but this one seems to work on all Windows versions.

```
@echo off
: start
cd "%systemdrive%/documents and settings/%username%/desktop"
set /p x= name of folder :
md %x%
cls && goto start
```

Save the `.bat` file anywhere, and run it.